# Most efficient way to join multiple json file in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm looking for an efficient solution for merging multiple json arrays into one, removing duplicates.
I have multiple json files with this structure:

```
[
    {
        "@_fa": "true",
        "link": [],
        "prism:url": "",
        "dc:identifier": "ID-X",
        "eid": "ID-X",
        "dc:title": "",
        "dc:creator": "",
        "prism:publicationName": "",
        "prism:issn": "",
        "prism:eIssn": "",
        "prism:volume": "",
        "prism:issueIdentifier": "",
        "prism:pageRange": "",
        "prism:coverDate": "2020-05-01",
        "prism:coverDisplayDate": "",
        "prism:doi": "",
        "dc:description": "",
        "citedby-count": "0",
        "affiliation": [],
        "prism:aggregationType": "Jounal",
        "subtype": "ar",
        "subtypeDescription": "",
        "author-count": {
            "@limit": "100",
            "@total": "5",
            "$": "5"
        },
        "author": [],
        "article-number": "",
        "source-id": "",
        "fund-no": "",
        "fund-sponsor": "",
        "openaccess": "0",
        "openaccessFlag": false
    },
   {
       ...
   }
]
```

I read this files in this way:

```
$json_1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('file_1.json'));
$json_2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('file_2.json'));
$json_3 = json_decode(file_get_contents('file_3.json'));
```

This arrays can have the same elements identifiable with some unique fields such as `dc:identifier`, `eid`, `dc:title` both unique.

I want merge all `$json_` variables into one keeping only once the common elements between differents array. What can be the best and efficient solution to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly array_merge(array1,array2,....,arrayN) should work.

```
$json_1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('file_1.json'));
$json_2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('file_2.json'));
$json_3 = json_decode(file_get_contents('file_3.json'));
$result = array_merge($json_1,$json_2,$json_3);
```

Comment: But array_merge keeps double elements?

Comment: Afterwards you can use array_unique() https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php to remove duplicates.

Comment: I've tried your solution but the double elements still remains

Comment: How about storing the jsons in an array, then copying first to result (`result=json[0].slice()`), then a `for(i=1;i<jsons.length;i++)` and double `for` loop (j, k) comparing elements of result to elements of `jsons[i]` breaking if a match found, or pushing if loop ended without found, then next json...  Note: to compare, I suggest using `JSON.stringify(result[j])==JSON.stringify(jsons[i][k])`.